# Windows 7: how do I find the setting for safe mode which was inadvertently set as default; it will not boot up in normal mode

Tags: safe-mode, windows-7-restore

In Windows 7 how do I find the setting to make normal mode my default?
The setting for safe mode was inadvertently set to default, and now my computer will not boot up in normal mode.

Answer (score 5):

The toggle for the default is usually in `msconfig`:

1. Hit <kbd>Super + R</kbd> (super is the windows key)
2. Type `msconfig` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
3. Under the `boot` tab, check the `Boot Options` (bottom left)
4. Double check the checkbox on the right 'Make all boot settings permanent' is as you want it (but I would suggest testing a reboot before setting that to checked to not lock yourself out if something else is afoot).

[image]

You should be able to toggle that from within Safemode.  But if not, during boot spam <kbd>F8</kbd> and it may give you the options to choose another boot mode and toggle it once you're in.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to set the following registry value from 1 to 0:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Option\OptionValue
```

Administrator rights are required to do this. Start `regedit.exe` via <kbd>Super+R</kbd>.

I am not sure why this registry hack could be required, but it has happened on my Win 7 systems several times.